# Woocommerce get product price by id in simple page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to a php file that can show a product's price by id. I have tried doing this with this code in a "price.php" file with this content:

I'm sure that something that links this with wp is missing, but what?

```
<?php
$price = get_post_meta( '225', '_regular_price', true);
echo $price;
?>
```

Comment: Both your method and AddWeb Solution Pvt Ltd's method should work fine. Your example probably isn't working because the first parameter in `get_post_meta` should be a `int`, you're sending a `string`. Try removing the single quotes from 255 in your example.

Answer (score 4):

If you have product's ID you can use that to create product object:

```
$product = new WC_Product($product_id);

After Creating Object you can run any of WooCommerce's product methods.

$product->get_regular_price();
$product->get_sale_price();
$product->get_price();
```

Comment: Hi! How to get product id?